# New activity without xml layout in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create new `Activity` class in `Android studio` , two `XML` layout files will generate automatically.

One of them have same name with my `Activity` and other `XML` file have name like : Content_[activity name].XML

Now, how can i turn off this auto generating work in `Android Studio`?

> I want to create new activities in android studio without any `XML` layout
>   file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps

1) Right click on your package name in which you want to create Activity.

2) Move your mouse cursor to New->Activity->Empty Activity.

3) Click on Empty Activity. you will see following window. **"Unmark Generate Layout File"**

[image]

4) Click Finish

Done...!!

Comment: yes , it's right way 
i used this menu (New->Activity->Blank Activity) before and in this case i can't select or not Generating Layout file

Comment: You didn't see "Generate layout file" check box ?

Comment: No! in right click menu to create new activity" Blank Activity != Empty Activity "
i used Blank Activity menu to create new Activity
, if you test in Android Studio you can see when you click on Blank Activity you have not any choice Generate layout file , BUT when you select Empty Activity you can unchecke it !

Comment: Yes, exactly. Blank activity create activity with coordinator layout and it also creates layout for our content insertion.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want Android to Studio to generate the xml files for you, You must do every steps on your own.

1. Create a java class which extends from activity.
2. Create a layout resource file.
3. Override OnCreate method in your activity and set your layout.
4. Add the new activity in manifest.

That's it.